# How to change HTML table cell by clicking and changing last change cell to original using JavaScript – (Switchboard)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a HTML table, and each cell has a value “Off”. When a user click on a cell I want to change that value of only that cell to “On” and if the user click another cell change it to “On” put the previously changed cell back to “Off”. Ie. Only one cell shows as “On” and all the others will be “Off”. This must be done using JavaScript and JQuery only (NOT angularJS)

```
<table id="switchboard-container">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="switch">Off</td>
            <td class="switch">Off</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="switch">Off</td>
            <td class="switch">Off</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is what I tried:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#switchboard-container td').click(function ()
    {
        setClickHandlers();
    });

    function setClickHandlers() {
        // Click handlers that change the content of switches to 'On' or 'Off'.
        var cells = document.querySelectorAll('# switchboard -container td');

        Array.prototype.forEach.call(cells, function (td) {
            td.addEventListener('click', changeCell);
        });
    }

    function changeCell() {
        if (this.textContent == "On")
        {
            this.textContent == "Off";
        }
        else
        {
            this.textContent = "On";
        }
    }
</script>
```

I can change to “On” but I don’t know how to set other cells to “Off. Can some one please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/3fh4mLba/1/

Basically, adding `$(".switch").text("Off");` will set the text to "Off" for all of them before you change it to on.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a simple click handler to do this

```js
$('#switchboard-container td.switch').click(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  if ($this.hasClass('on')) { //if the current element is on then we can just make it off
    $this.text('Off');
  } else {
    $this.text('On'); //make the current td on
    $('#switchboard-container td.switch.on').removeClass('on').text('Off'); //make other td which are on as off
  }
  $this.toggleClass('on');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="switchboard-container">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="switch">Off</td>
      <td class="switch">Off</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="switch">Off</td>
      <td class="switch">Off</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```